# Mongodb condition criteria on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bigdata

Mongo Eaters....

Just a small question. Follow these queries i have made

```
db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:1,world:1}});
```

when i do

```
db.trip.find({loc:{hello:1,world:1}});
```

i get results but when i do

```
db.trip.find({loc:{hello:1}});
```

i dont get results, actually i want to get the documents which has loc.hello as 1 irrespective of any other loc properties

Please this is just a scenario, i have more complex problem, but this is the root cause, please help me so that other people dont get caught in this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation for inner document

```
db.trip.find({"loc.hello":1})
```

See following run.

```
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:1,world:1}});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.trip.find({"loc.hello":1})                                                                
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5475bed907fbea3cf13e14d6"), "loc" : { "hello" : 1, "world" : 1 } }         
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:2,world:1}});                                                     
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })                                                               
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:3,world:1}});                                                     
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })                                                               
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:4,world:1}});                                                     
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })                                                               
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:4,world:1}});                                                     
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })                                                               
> db.trip.insert({loc:{hello:4,world:2}});                                                     
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })                                                               
> db.trip.find({"loc.hello":4})                                                                
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5475bf2907fbea3cf13e14d9"), "loc" : { "hello" : 4, "world" : 1 } }         
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5475bf2b07fbea3cf13e14da"), "loc" : { "hello" : 4, "world" : 1 } }         
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5475bf2d07fbea3cf13e14db"), "loc" : { "hello" : 4, "world" : 2 } }
```

Comment: thank you, you really saved me, one thing more if you can really help me, suppose there is array also in between, then how to use it with . notation

Comment: i mean suppose there loc:[{hello:1},{hello:2},{hello:3}], then how to make criteria on second element like "loc[2].hello":2, right?